# 200 vs 403 server response - which degrades server's performance more?

Tags: server, query-performance

Some rogue people have set up server monitoring that connects to server every 2 minutes to check if it's down (they connect from several different accounts so they ping the server every 20 seconds or so). It's a simple GET request.

I have two options:

1. Leave it as it is (ie. allow them via a normal 200 server response).
2. Block them by either IP or user-agent (giving 403 response).

My question is - what is the better solution as far as server performance is concerned (ie. what is less 'stressful' on the server) - 1 (200 response) or 2 (403 response)?

I'm inclined to #1 since there would be no IP / user-agent checking which should mean less stress on the server, correct?

Comment: 403 won't really "block" them in the sense of stopping them from sending requests to the server.  If these rogues are in your company, best is to report them to management.  If not, firewall.  Also, you do have a proper robots.txt file, right?

Comment: These are either paid or free 'server monitoring' services.. I have no control over them (other than blocking them via .htaccess).

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter.

The status code and an if-check on the user-string is completely dominated by network IO, gc and server subsystems.

If they just query every 2 minutes, I'd very much leave it alone. If they query a few hundred times per second; time to act.

Comment: 2 minute queries from several accounts so it's more like one query every 20-30 seconds..

Comment: Still completely within ignorable territory. If it's an issue, firewall the hosts away instead (iptables / windows firewall).